# Use of 'secondo' in different contexts

Tags: word-usage, idioms, phrase-choice

As a passionate Italian learner, I find myself on this website a lot. What I enjoy about the website is that askers might find themselves posting their question in English or even Italian. For the most part, I am able to fully comprehend what the asker is confused about when the question is written in Italian. What intrigues me, however, is a commonality I find in many Italian-written questions.

This commonality is the phrase *Secondo il...* or *Secondo me...*, even *Secondo voi*. From studying Italian so far, I've only seen the word *secondo* used in the context of inferring **second**. Thus, this brings me to my question, how exactly is *secondo* being used in these types of phrases?

Comment: Apart from being the measure unit of time in the International System, and a subunit of the sexagesimal degrees (both translated to `second`), `secondo` has essentially two meanings: "immediately after the first" and "according to". For each of those two it has a lot of uses, which roughly correspond to the ones those two expression have in English (including the double usage as a noun or as an adjective). For further details, look [here](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/secondo.php) and ask if you can't understand something.

Comment: For *secondo*, both the meaning of “second” (= after the first) and of “according to”, interestingly, derive from the Latin verb *sequi*, “to follow”, via the adjective *secundus*. In the former case, of course, a second person or item follows the first; in the latter, we are talking of “following” an opinion or a model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, this question about *secondo* comes up fairly early when beginning speakers start talking about their opinions.

English speakers infer that Italians are saying *second* like 'he's second in line', and while there is a direct correspondence to that particular meaning -- Italians also use *secondo* as an ordinal number for 2 -- this is not the sense to which you refer.

More commonly, *secondo* is used to **express opinions**, as in:

> *secondo me, lui è molto bravo in matematica ma stenta in italiano.*
>
> (In my opinion, he is very good at math, but struggles with Italian.)

Also, secondo is used in the sense of **according to**, as in:

> *secondo la fonte* (according to the source)
>
> *secondo Antonio Gramsci* (according to Antonio Gramsci)

Answer (score 1):

It means "from one's point of view" and "regarding" also.
"Secondo me..." :  in my opinion...
"Secondo il risultato ottenuto..." : regarding the obtained results...
"Secondo piano"  : second floor

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Can you please expand your answer?